# .xlsm file working in Excel-2013, not working in Excel-2016

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, excel-2016

I'am developing a tool in Excel, where I use a few macros. Around one month ago, when I tried to open the file in my Excel 2016, I got a "no response" when I enabled the macros. It was all right before that. Moreover, when this happened, all my saved files from past 3 months were not working aswell.

Does anyone have any idea, what could be the reason for that?

I use some userforms, for example one which asks for password to the file, opened by the workbook_open() sub.

Comment: You can compare the Trust Center Macro Settings on both and maybe check if one of them is 64 bit.

Comment: save as binary... try to open in 2016 and save back to xlsm

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Can you try changing your Excel settings to always allow macros without asking? If it doesn't help, try commenting out workbook_open() sub in Excel 2013, and then open with 2016, see how it works, whether it's only this one part causing malfunction.

Comment: If I comment this, the file is working until I use another macro, like a button that adds row to a table.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with the version differences due to the fact 2016 basically has no real changes to the vba. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-5fdb9208-ff33-45b6-9e08-1f5cdb3a6c73?ui=en-US&amp;amp;amp;rs=en-US&amp;amp;amp;ad=US

Comment: Use the VBA debugger to check where it is crashing. Use Breakpoints when entering your critical functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out, that I need to do an actualization of my excel 2016 in order to make it work. I have no idea, why it was not working, the weird part is that i have downloaded the excel 2016 in the same day, so I was expecting it to be updated. Anyway, it worked.